# How to launch a conditinated selection of dataframe's row with mixed values

Tags: python, if-statement, select, conditional-statements, row

I am trying to use the conditioned selection of interested rows/columns into the followng dataset:

```
import pandas as pd

already_read = [("Il nome della rosa","Umberto Eco", 1980), 
        ("L'amore che ti meriti","Daria Bignardi", 2014), 
        ("Memorie dal sottsuolo", " Fëdor Dostoevskij", 1864), 
        ("Oblomov", "Ivan Alexandrovich Goncharov ", '/')]

index = range(1,5,1)
data = pd.DataFrame(already_read, columns = ["Books'Title", "Authors", "Publishing Year"], index = index)
data
```

In the following way:

```
data[(data['Publishing Year'] >= 1850) & (data['Publishing Year'] <= 1950)]
```

As you could see, the column I have chosen contains mixed data `(int and str)` and indeed I have this error after running the code:

```
TypeError: '>=' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'
```

If please, since I'm moving my very first step with Python, could you please suggest some way to run that code in a way that the string value is excluded or it is read as an integer, possibly by implementing `*if statement?*` (or another method)?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to go, would be to use [`df.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) with a custom function. Something like this:

```
def check_int(x):
    if isinstance(x, int):
        return (x >= 1850) & (x <= 1950)
    return False

data[data['Publishing Year'].apply(lambda x: check_int(x))]
```

Here `check_int` will return `False` for every value that is not an `int`, and apply the evaluation just on the `ints`. So, we are getting:

```
data['Publishing Year'].apply(lambda x: check_int(x))

1    False
2    False
3     True
4    False
Name: Publishing Year, dtype: bool
```

And next we use this pd.Series with `booleans` to select from the data:

```
data[data['Publishing Year'].apply(lambda x: check_int(x))]

             Books'Title             Authors Publishing Year
3  Memorie dal sottsuolo   Fëdor Dostoevskij            1864
```

Comment: It is a very pretty nice code. Thanks, I am going to study your response then I will question something if you please. I do not know whether you could recommend as well some methods to manage this kind of mixed dataset information (possibly, just by changing the code `data[(data['Publishing Year'] >= 1850) & (data['Publishing Year'] <= 1950)] )`. Thank you so much